# regex look ahead behind (look around) negative problems

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am having trouble understanding negative regex lookahead / lookbehind. I got the impression from reading tutorials that when you set a criteria to look for, the criteria doesn't form part of the search match.

That seems to hold for positive lookahead examples I tried, but when I tried these negative ones, it matches the entire test string. 1, it shouldn't have matched anything, and 2 even if it did, it wasn't supposed to include the lookahead criteria??

```
(?<!^And).*\.txt$
```

with input

```
And.txt
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/vW0aXS/1

and

```
^A.*(?!\.txt$)
```

with input:

```
A.txt
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/70yeED/1

PS: if you're going to ask me which language. I don't know. we've been told to use regex without any specific reference to any specific languages. I tried clicking various options on regex101.com and they all came up the same.

Comment: at the beginning of the string, the lookbehind can't "look back" and see "AND". Conversely, at the end of the string, the lookahead doesn't see ".txt", as it has already matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookarounds only try to match at their current position.

You are using a lookbehind at the *beginning* of the string `(?<!^And).*\.txt$`, and a lookahead at the *end* of the string `^A.*(?!\.txt$)`, which won't work. (`.*` will always consume the whole string as it's first match)

To disallow "And", for example, you can put the lookahead at the beginning of the string with a greedy quantifier `.*` *inside* it, so that it scans the whole string:

```
 (?!.*And).*\.txt$
```

https://regex101.com/r/1vF50O/1

Comment: i think your answer is the correct one for the case i've outlined. i seem to have stumbed upon an edge case by accident then! good to know the thing about lookaround only matching at current positions. will look up more on that works

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/XoyK7T/1   is that another example of "lookarounds only matching at their current position? because other wise lookarounds don't include the criteria inside the result

Comment: yes. the lookahead fails on the first try (it sees an 'a'), the engine moves over one character to the right, tries again, this time the lookaround sees a 'b', and then the `[a-z]*` matches "bcd".

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct and the issue is not with the lookbehind/lookahead. The issue is with `.*` which matches the entire string in both cases. The period `.` matches any character and then you follow it with `*` which makes it match the entire string of any length. Remove it and both you regexes will work:

```
(?<!^And)\.txt$

^A(?!\.txt$)
```